# Get url of image from Plotly.toImage func

Tags: reactjs, es6-promise, plotly.js

Currently I'am working on math app with React and Plotly.js. The base of my problem is how to get url value of image from `Plotly.toImage()` function. I always get Promise object when I try to assign value from function to source of some image. Here is my code:

```js
class Export extends Component{
    async getImage(div) {
        const url = await Plotly.toImage(div, {format: 'svg'});
        return url;
    }
    render(){
        var url = this.getImage('main');
        return(
            <div className='input-container'>
               <img src={url} alt='Export previev' width={450} height={300}/>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

I want to display image of plot in browser as single image.

Answer (score 0):

Problem resolved by setting src atribute of reference to image instead of storing Promise return value.

```js
class Export extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.imgRef = React.createRef();
    }
    async getImage() {
        const div = document.querySelector('.js-plotly-plot');
        const url = await Plotly.toImage(div, {format: 'svg'});
        this.imgRef.current.src = url;
    };
    render(){
        this.getImage();
        return(
            <div className='input-container'>
               <img ref={this.imgRef} alt='Export previev' width={263}/>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```